File generated by PyInstaller does not work on MacOS
I am trying to create a .dmg file from a python script in order to distribute it. For this I am using pyinstaller. I run the commands specified in the documentation (such as pyinstaller --name 'Monitoring' --windowed  monitoring.py --onefile), but after the build and dist directories are created, when I run the application, it doesn't even open.
The code I want to package is:
from requests import Session
from collections import OrderedDict
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op
import tkinter as tk
import json

# Excel read
df = pd.read_excel('Monitoring.xlsx')
nameList = df['Unnamed: 2'].tolist()[1:23]

def getPrices():
    prices = OrderedDict() # Insertion-ordered dict
    coinPrice = [] # Result list
    coins = getCoins()

    # Define dict keys
    for name in nameList:
        prices[name] = ""

    # Define dict values
    for coin in prices.keys():
        prices[coin] = coins[coin][0]["quote"]["USD"]["price"]

    # Insert in the result list
    for item in prices.items():
        coinPrice.append(item[1])

    # Load the file to work with
    workbook = op.load_workbook('Monitoring.xlsx')
    # Change the cell values
    for x in range(0, len(coinPrice)):
        sheet["O" + str(x+3)] = coinPrice[x]

    # Save the changes in the same file
    workbook.save('Monitoring.xlsx')

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Monitoring")

    prices = tk.Button(prices, text="Prices", command=getPrices)
    prices.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=2)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Otherwise, this is what the code of the .spec file looks like:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['monitoring.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Monitoring',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
app = BUNDLE(
    exe,
    name='Monitoring.app',
    icon=None,
    bundle_identifier=None,
)


I do not know if the problem is related to the dependencies I use (e.g. pandas), but if it is, I do not know where I should specify them.
I also tried to use other libraries such us py2app but it did not work neither.
Thanks in advance!

Include the error you get when you try to run your program in the question.

If you're only trying to run it at a GUI, open up a terminal window and try to run it there -- otherwise you can't see the logs so there's no information to know why it didn't work.

That's the problem: everything gets generated but when I am trying to open de .app file it does not work and I have no error shown in the console... In the same way, if I run the program using the terminal it works good

Have you tried opening the .app from the terminal? (See man open on MacOS). That lets you use --stdout and --stderr to control where logging goes.

I guess you might want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78290574/20782948 thank me later
